# Report : Save hierarchy level not working

Tags: custom-reports, role-hierarchy

When a user creates a report with specific filters, they were unable to see results. As a admin i'm enabling the Save Hierarchy Level in report properties. After some time again the user cant see the data in reports,then i have to enable again and save the reports. Is there any permanent solution to this save hierarchy level setting?